# Modded PC CPU upgrade - will the power supply manage?

Tags: processor, power-supply, power

I have a motherboard FOXCONN H61 with a Celeron CPU.
I'd like to upgrade the CPU to possibly a i7-2600 or a i7-3770 (looking for used/renewed ones).

Now here's the thing: I power the motherboard with a [PicoPSU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0035UETHW) power supply, nominal "PicoPSU-90 12V DC Input 90 Watt Output + 60W Adapter Power Kit" .

Will this be able to handle the loads from those CPUs? The i7-3770 is tagged with 77W, while the i7-2600 with 95W...

Not sure how exactly those wattages are related, but I am sure it's posing some limits...

Comment: If the power cable has an inline adapter that supplies 60W then that is the limit for the whole system including fans, hard drives, USB ports, etc. Those i7 CPUs need more than 60W of power to run at full performance. It would be unwise to use them with a 60W power supply. If you get a new power cable with a 90W brick then it it might be enough.

Comment: That's more or less what I expected, but good to have someone else confirm. Thank you!